# How to get textarea value and replace it with user updated textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, textarea

The code below displays the content of index.html in a textarea. 
What i'm trying to achieve is that the user can edit the text displayed to him and press "submit" and thus saving the textarea contents in a document. I'm only using Node and Express..

```
app.get('/edit', function(req, res) {
var html = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
var body = '<html>' + 
        '<head>' + 
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; ' + 
        'charset=UTF-8" />' +
        '</head>' + 
        '<body>' + 
        '<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
        '<textarea autofocus name="edit" rows="35" cols="70">' +
        html +
        '</textarea>' +
        '<input type="submit" value="save" />' +
        '</form>' +
        '</body>' +
        '</html>';

res.send(body);
```

Comment: you need to catch the POST in express, but you also have a major problem if someone types in "</textarea>". for editing, it's thus better to serve an empty textarea and then fill it using ajax, which allows any html tags (valid or otherwise) to be edited in the textarea. as shown, once you click the button you should be sending the edited contents back to node, but you might need an action attribute on the form.

Comment: Okay, but what exactly is your question? Is it related to handling/escaping markup within form fields? Or is it related to server-side processing of posted values? Please tell us where you got stuck.